# z/OS ftp: 550 Unable to create data set E043156.UNIX.USERLIB.SOME for STOR command

Tags: ftp, zos

I'm trying to upload a file from linux to z/OS via ftp (with filezilla). The upload fails with this error:

```
550-SVC99 RETURN CODE=4 S99INFO=0 S99ERROR=38668 HEX=970C S99ERSN code X'000042CE'.
550 Unable to create data set TESTUSER.UNIX.USERLIB.SOME for STOR command.
```

Does anyone know how to interpret this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SVC99`, also known as `DYNALLOC`, is the dynamic allocation routine on z/OS.  Documentation is voluminous, see the [IBM Documentation for z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos) and look under z/OS MVS -> z/OS MVS Programming: Authorized Assembler Services -> Dynamic Allocation -> Requesting Dynamic Allocation Functions -> Interpreting Error Reason Codes from DYNALLOC.  For z/OS 2.2 that path should take you [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=codes-interpreting-error-reason-from-dynalloc).

> Meaning: Severe SMS VTOC service error.
>
> Application programmer action:
> Check field S99ERSN for a non-zero value. A non-zero value in S99ERSN
> is a reason code. [See SMS reason code (S99ERSN)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=fields-sms-reason-code-s99ersn) for the possible
> reason codes. If the system displayed message IKJ56893I, SMS messages
> for the error follow IKJ56893I. If the system displayed message
> IKJ56894I, no messages were returned. Request the message processing
> option of dynamic allocation to obtain related messages and resubmit
> the request. Because SMS creates entries in the logrec data set, if
> you still cannot obtain messages, locate the logrec data set entry for
> the error that corresponds to the reason code. If you need further
> assistance contact your system programmer.
>
> Corresponding Messages: IKJ56893I (messages were displayed) or
> IKJ56894I (messages not displayed).

Following the link, your S99ERSN code is documented as...

> 42CE (17102)
>
> Meaning: While trying to define a non-VSAM data set, a catalog error or
> exceptional condition caused the allocation attempt to fail.
>
> Application Programmer Action: Examine the return code and reason
> code in accompanying message IGD17102I in [z/OS MVS System Messages,
> Vol 8 (IEF-IGD)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zm-zos-mvs-system-messages-vol-8-ief-igd).

So there should be an accompanying message [IGD17102I](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=messages-igd17102i) in the system log with even more information.  Looking at the documentation, I'd contact your support staff as this doesn't look like something you can fix yourself.